# Wordplay puzzle for you

Tags: discussion

I've just posted [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/33133/13535) over at Puzzling.SE and on at least some of the questions, English Language Learners may have some advantage over native [especially American] English speakers who might get more easily sidetracked by "correct" pronunciations.  It might be a fun exercise to see how many, if any, you can get.  Understanding puns in a new language, and even being able to come up with them or match from a list, is a nice confidence booster.  Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for sharing - it's a fun puzzle! For learners that aren't familiar with US cities, this list of cities may help make the puzzle a little easier (I think all of the answers are on there): http://www.infoplease.com/ipa/A0108676.html

Comment: I'm... somewhat confused. Is this what Meta is for? Doesn't this belong in Chat? Why is this on-topic on Meta? I'm just curious. :)

Comment: If resource requests are on-topic on Meta I don't see why sharing posts from other SEs that might be interesting/helpful to English learners should be obviously off-topic.

Comment: @Colleen then it's time to question their being on-topic. People want to embrace anything that's useful. That is not useful since it makes meta a mess.

Comment: @TIPS We simply don't have enough traffic on meta to worry that much about it in my opinion.  As long as it's relevant to learning English and of interest to some portion of the community, I don't see the harm. If this was down-voted into the negative, I think I might view it differently.

Comment: @Colleen sure, people sometimes upvote *and* close vote a question. I wouldn't worry about it if meta remained like this, but of course with a growing ELL we'll get a growing meta.ELL. I don't want to see people complaining in the future that "why is this [question](link) on-topic on meta even though mine isn't?" We could really make use of this stuff as chat events.